# How to make the thumbnails of a malihu-jquery-image-gallery slider to loop without stopping

Tags: jquery, slider, image-gallery

I have implemented the image gallery slider using the below links.

[malihu image gallery slider-demo](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/malihu-jquery-image-gallery/malihu-jquery-image-gallery.html)

[malihu image gallery slider-code](https://github.com/TinyGiantStudios/tpnd/blob/master/js/fullscreen/malihu-jquery-image-gallery.html)

On hover over the thumbnails after the final thumbnail image the scroll stopped.I need to make the thumbnail keep on scrolling.

Comment: Hi can you add relevant code to the actual question? just incase the site/code is not available in future..`Do you want the scroller to continue scrolling back to the start??`
(Thats a pretty sweet looking site.)

Comment: Sorry the code is too large.how we can add the entire code here? Yes i need the scroller to continue scrolling back to the start. @JF it

Comment: Can you fix up this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/faX95/ just to replicate functionality, realistically though your scroller will need some extra functionality, repositioning the first few images using .remove/append based on the position of the scroller..

Comment: dont need the images working btw, just the scrolling functionality.. the image missing boxes are fine.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n3pav/ Updated fiddle. Have to add jquery easin1.3 js also to the fiddle.@JF it

Comment: Still not working for me :/

Comment: Kindly update the fiddle with jquery easing1.3 js and try once@JF it

Comment: Yeah i did, sorry something wrong.. what browser u using? im on chrome..

Comment: my origonal http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/faX95/ has easing in external resources on left side.

Comment: Have u make the thumbnail to scroll?@JF it

Comment: can't make the thumbnail to scroll.Anybody please suggest some way to get it.Kindly check with the demo link.@JF it